# Android menu, throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException while running onPrepareOptionsMenu

Tags: android, exception, menu, menuitem

When I try to update my MenuItem in menu I recieve IndexOutOfBoundsException.

I've added menu_item in xml and I can see it when enable() == false.

My code:

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if ( enable() ) {
        MenuItem menuItem= menu.getItem(R.id.menu_item);
        menuItem.setEnabled(true);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

How to deal with the problem?

Cheers.

Comment: You might want to call `super.onPrepareOptionsMenu` before accessing its contents. Also use `Menu.findItem` instead.

Comment: Ok, after changing getItem to findItem, app doesn't thorow exception. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 56):

Just had the same problem. Happens if you accidentally use the `getItem()` instead of `findItem()`.

```
MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to Clean your project to update the values of R.
If you prefer another way, you can do

```
for(int i = 0; i<menu.size();++i)
{
    if(menu.getItem(i).getItemId() == R.id.menu_item)
         MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(i);
}
```

or opt for a more beautiful

menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item);